# Calculate velocity profile given a distance and time

Tags: kinematics, velocity

I want to calculate the velocity profile with constant deceleration to reach a goal position exactly at given timepoint.

So, I have given a position, duration (the position should be reached after the duration with final velocity 0), an initial velocity, a max. desired velocity, a deceleration.
The initial velocity is higher than the desired maximum velocity, so that it first needs to decelerate to an unknown velocity and then later decelerate with the same deceleration to stop at the correct position (area under curve is given and fixed) after the correct duraton.

I made a drawing to make it more clear: v is searched, the rest is given. (a is the deceleration, vMax is probably not relevant)

[image]

How can I find this velocity?

Comment: Are the times given for when the deceleration takes place ?

Comment: No, they are unknown.

Comment: Can you please make the situation in the question clearer, do you mean a way for which the minimum time is taken?

Comment: No, the way  (=distance) and duration are given. It should reach the goal position exactly at the given time. I'll try to make it clearer in the question.

Comment: Is it essential for it to have a constant velocity in between?

Comment: Yes, I can give the position controller only a velocity, an acceleration,  a deceleration and the target position. But the desired acceleration/deceleration/position is given by the user.

Comment: This is impossible to solve for a numerical value if at least one of the times for which a deceleration takes place is not given.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Maybe I can reformulate the problem statement.

Comment: Yes please, just post the original question and your attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

I changed the representation to this, which is equivalent:
[image]

Then I can find the velocity easily:

`dt1 = v0/a;
            dt2 = t - dt1;
            deltaX = v0 * v0 / 2.f / a + v0 * dt0;
            v = (distance - deltaX ) / dt1;`